# how to save multi message in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I am working on a real time chat project using: nodejs, express, socket.io, redis, mongodb.
I want to ask people how to save messages on mongodb.
I tried to save each chat line into mongodb, but too many chats saved quite a lot, when I want to access it, I have to access too much.
Is there an optimal way to save this case.
Thanks everyone !

Comment: Storing each message as its own document sounds like a reasonable first option. Slow query problem can be mitigated by adding indexes to your database and improving hardware capacity (more DB servers, bigger DB servers)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try limiting messages.
For example get last 10 entries

```
db.getLastInsertedDocument.find({}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(10);
```